# Why are zero variables shown after using drop_na()?

Tags: r, tidyr

After drop_na it shows 0 obs. of 68 variables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After drop_na I don't see any results in the Table except dates. This was not the case when I tried it before, I could see the values ​​in the table.

```r
> library(tidyverse)
> WDI_GDP <- read_csv("C:/Users/ASYA/Desktop/P_Data_Extract_From_World_Development_Indicators/b0351889-13b3-4cbe-a5c0-a2dd9d633eab_Data.csv")

> library(tidyverse)

> WDI_GDP <- read_csv("C:/Users/ASYA/Desktop/P_Data_Extract_From_World_Development_Indicators/b0351889-13b3-4cbe-a5c0-a2dd9d633eab_Data.csv")

> WDI_GDP <- WDI_GDP %>% 
+   mutate(across(contains("[YR"), ~na_if(.x,"..")) %>% 
+   mutate(across(contains("[YR"), as.numeric)))
> WDI_GDP <- drop_na(WDI_GDP)
>
```

[image]

Comment: Presumably one or more of the columns containing `[YR` are character data that is not converting to numeric, creating NAs which you then drop. We can only speculate since you haven't shared any example data. e.g. you could run `dput(WDI_GDP[1:5, 2:6])` to share the first 5 rows and columns #2-6 as code that includes the data formats and structure, which are necessary context for many R questions.

Comment: 'structure(list(`Country Code` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Series Name` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    `Series Code` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), `1960 [YR1960]` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `1961 [YR1961]` = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))'                         problem is still... @ JonSpring

Comment: Welcome to SO, asya! Comments are poorly suited for code and data, please [edit] your question and add it there into a [code block]. While you're there ... it can be frustrating that users new to Stack sites cannot show linked images by default. Please don't try to figure out how to get them to show, it won't let you, please just leave the image-markdown alone and work around it. Eventually (usually within an hour or so) one of us will edit your question for you to make them visible to everybody. I've fixed it for now.

Comment: Similarly, screenshots are fine, but they should not be the only access we have to code/data/errors. I think in this case, the last two images don't add much, so they can be removed. When you want to demonstrate that an expression results in 0 rows, that can be shown _in text_ using `nrow(x); x <- drop_na(x); nrow(x)` (or whatever expressions were used ... namely just show `nrow` before and after an action). The first image is "okay", but your addition of the `dput(.)` output is by far better and more importantly _usable_ by us, otherwise I'm not transcribing data from an image into my R.

Comment: Last comment for now ... the sample data you added a few comments ago is not helpful in demonstrating how to remove rows with `NA` values, since that frame is entirely `NA` values. Please share `dput(head(WDI_GDP))` immediately after reading in the data, before you clean up and remove-NA.